Adding railing to roof with TPO membrane
I have a flat roof on the back of my home that's covered with a white TPO membrane. Since this area is quite large, we're considering turning it into a second floor patio. All the joints appear to be quite well-sealed by the installers and I want to ensure I don't introduce any leaks.
We need to install a railing for this to be a usable space and obviously that railing will need to be screwed down to the roof structure. What's the best way to do so while preventing leaks where the screw holes are?
So far, the best advice I've found is to use a butyl seal tape such as this or this. I would plan to lay this under the area where the railing is going. Then I would also need some sealant around the screw holes. What sort of sealant is best and how should it be applied? I've seen different advice on this such as:

Drill a pilot hole, fill that with sealant and put sealant around the hole, then screw down
Coat the screw with some sealant, then insert the screw
Drill a hole and then put in some epoxy and put the screw in before it cures

Any advice on which of these methods (or some other alternate method) would work best would be great!
